# How to use same Dynamic input field multiple times

Tags: jquery

I trying to create dynamic input field, Found this code but unable to use this code twice. I mean two different dynamic input field.I have added the code.There is limited input field can be added, in this.Please help

Here is the Html code

```
<section class="section a_UFMNX">
    <par-div class="par-label"><label for="auth">Author<span>*</span><i class="bi bi-question-circle infor"></i>
            <par-sep class="ctooltip">Enter Author's Name</par-sep>
        </label></par-div>
    <par-div class="par-input-sm">
        <par-sep id="dynamic-field-1" class="par-input-sm dynamic-field">
            <input class="input-sm in-color" placeholder="Author" type="text" id="field" name="field[]">
        </par-sep>
        <button type="button" id="add-button" class="addmorebtn">Add More</button>
        <button type="button" id="remove-button" class="removebtn" disabled="disabled">Remove Last</button>
    </par-div>
</section>
```

Here is the Jquery code

```
var buttonAdd = $("#add-button");
var buttonRemove = $("#remove-button");
var className = ".dynamic-field";
var count = 0;
var field = "";
var maxFields = 5;

function totalFields() {
    return $(className).length;
}

function addNewField() {
    count = totalFields() + 1;
    field = $("#dynamic-field-1").clone();
    field.attr("id", "dynamic-field-" + count);
    field.children("label").text("Field " + count);
    field.find("input").val("");
    field.css({ 'margin': '5px 0' });
    $(className + ":last").after($(field));
}

function removeLastField() {
    if (totalFields() > 1) {
        $(className + ":last").remove();
    }
}

function enableButtonRemove() {
    if (totalFields() === 2) {
        buttonRemove.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}

function disableButtonRemove() {
    if (totalFields() === 1) {
        buttonRemove.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

function disableSEC() {
    if (totalFields() === maxFields) {
        buttonAdd.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

function enableSEC() {
    if (totalFields() === (maxFields - 1)) {
        buttonAdd.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}

buttonAdd.click(function () {
    addNewField();
    enableButtonRemove();
    disableSEC();
});

buttonRemove.click(function () {
    removeLastField();
    disableButtonRemove();
    enableSEC();
});
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Please ass the relevant html and script imports so that others can check the issue clearly

Comment: @Nitheesh Please Check once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code was in the `addNewField` function and that's the only thing I changed in this snippet. This is the function changed:

```
function addNewField() {
  count = totalFields() + 1;
  
  field = $("#dynamic-field-1").clone(true);
  field.attr("id", `dynamic-field-${count}`);
  field.find("input").val("");
  field.find("input").attr('id', `field-${count}`);
  field.css({'margin': '5px 0'});
  $(className + ":last").after($(field));
}
```

You were cloning an existing element to create the next dynamic field but you were not changing the id of the nested input element. Remember you cannot have two element with the same id in the document.

Now every input field will have a progressive id (using `count`) like you already did with the `dynamic-field`.

I also used string template literals instead of using concatenation.

I should also say that your `par-div` and `par-sep` elements are invalid in terms of html5 (unless you are using custom elements) and this whole strategy was better implemented using the `<template>` element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

> The <template> HTML element is a mechanism for holding HTML that is
> not to be rendered immediately when a page is loaded but may be
> instantiated subsequently during runtime using JavaScript.

And I also added the definition of the two custom elements `<par-div>` and `<par-sep>` so that both now have `display: block;` by default. Anyway it's worth saying that, if the functionality of those elements don't go further than that, it was far enough to have them a class bound to a css rule that styled them as such.

Now the rendering of the page is accurate and it's shown how to correctly define those.

```js
class ParDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.style.display = "block";
  }
}
class ParSep extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.style.display = "block";
  }
}
customElements.define("par-div", ParDiv, { extends: "div" });
customElements.define("par-sep", ParSep, { extends: "div" });

var buttonAdd = $("#add-button");
var buttonRemove = $("#remove-button");
var className = ".dynamic-field";
var count = 0;
var field = "";
var maxFields = 5;

function totalFields() {
  return $(className).length;
}

function addNewField() {
  count = totalFields() + 1;
  
  field = $("#dynamic-field-1").clone(true);
  field.attr("id", `dynamic-field-${count}`);
  field.find("input").val("");
  field.find("input").attr('id', `field-${count}`);
  field.css({'margin': '5px 0'});
  $(className + ":last").after($(field));
}

function removeLastField() {
  if (totalFields() > 1) {
    $(className + ":last").remove();
  }
}

function enableButtonRemove() {
  if (totalFields() === 2) {
    buttonRemove.removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}

function disableButtonRemove() {
  if (totalFields() === 1) {
    buttonRemove.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}

function disableSEC() {
  if (totalFields() === maxFields) {
    buttonAdd.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}

function enableSEC() {
  if (totalFields() === (maxFields - 1)) {
    buttonAdd.removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}

buttonAdd.click(function() {
  addNewField();
  enableButtonRemove();
  disableSEC();
});

buttonRemove.click(function() {
  removeLastField();
  disableButtonRemove();
  enableSEC();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="section a_UFMNX">
  <par-div class="par-label">
    <label for="auth">
      Author<span>*</span><i class="bi bi-question-circle infor"></i>
      <par-sep class="ctooltip">Enter Author's Name</par-sep>
    </label>
  </par-div>
  <par-div class="par-input-sm">
    <par-sep id="dynamic-field-1" class="par-input-sm dynamic-field">
      <input
        class="input-sm in-color"
        placeholder="Author"
        type="text"
        id="field"
        name="field[]">
    </par-sep>
    <button type="button" id="add-button" class="addmorebtn">Add More</button>
    <button
      type="button"
      id="remove-button"
      class="removebtn"
      disabled="disabled">Remove Last</button>
  </par-div>
</section>
```

Comment: This way tried to validate HTML TAGS class newTags extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
if (!customElements.get('par-div')) { 
  customElements.define('par-div', newTags); 
  var newtags = new newTags();
  newtags.style.display = "block";
}

Comment: ok it was just a further note I added in my answer to better cover everything I could see as far as I could see. Anyway the custom element part was not the issue here. You were having input elements having the same id and that's why maybe you were having problems. you can't query the document for elements having the same id and you can't fetch their values. Now with this further refactor, you can

Comment: Sir, I actually wanted to show so that you can guide me , the way I validated tag was right or wrong that is why I commented the script

Comment: I finally got your point with those custom elements. I edited the answer to include their correct definition and now the snippet it's shown as originally intended. It was just a matter of setting their display to block. But I couldn't get it before because it was such an easy customization that css was far enough to fulfill that need